# Error while trying to add an image to my facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Im trying to add a logo to my newly created facebook app. But every time I press the upload button an error message show up and says that my image has the wrong size.

The size of my image is 600x400px and it's in the png format. This should work. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: 1200x630 would be the recommended resolution according to the docs

Comment: A small hint on the upload modal says that the maximum would be 1024 × 1024 Pixel.

Comment: ah, my bad. i was thinking about og images. well, why not use a square image then?

Comment: Also tried it with a image with the exact sizes butt still the same problem. I think those are maximum values and not exact values. I will try to contact fb. Anyway thank you for your tipps